# How to make method return a panel?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I am making a Java application with tabbed pane, I want some panes to have the same panel layout and structure, I don't want to clutter my code by writing the same code over and over again, so I created a method that returns a JPanel with a structure I want the pane to have.

I am initialising new variables and taking them to the method . My problem is that after I create a panel I can not do anything else in it because it doesn't show up. I can not add labels etc, etc (although if I add the label in the method it does show).

My question is it possible to somehow change the code I've written to make it possible to change it after the panel is returned?

```
    JPanel panel2 =  panel2(); // this code bit is in the constructor
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();    //Variables needed to create a panel
    JPanel LeftPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel RightPanel = new JPanel();
    JSplitPane splitPaneH = new JSplitPane();
    JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
    JPanel panelBottom = new JPanel();

private JPanel panel2() {
        JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
        CreateAPanel(newPanel, LeftPanel,RightPanel,splitPaneH, panelTop,panelBottom);
        JLabel label = new JLabel ("lalala");
        LeftPanel.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        return newPanel;

}

private JPanel CreateAPanel(JPanel mainPanel, JPanel LeftPanel,JPanel RightPanel, JSplitPane splitPaneH, JPanel panelTop, JPanel panelBottom){
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1100, 630));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        LeftPanel = new JPanel();
        RightPanel = new JPanel();
        splitPaneH = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        panelTop = new JPanel();
        panelBottom = new JPanel();

        splitPaneH.setTopComponent(panelTop);
        splitPaneH.setBottomComponent(panelBottom);
        splitPaneH.setDividerLocation(300);
        splitPaneH.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,630));

        mainPanel.add(LeftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPanel.add(RightPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        LeftPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        LeftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (300,630));
        RightPanel.add(splitPaneH);

        return mainPanel;
}
```

Comment: unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Variable and method names should go camelCase in Java. UpperCase is for class names, thus your code is highly misleading for ordinary java programmers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not use your return value...

your method `CreateAPanel(...)` creates the desired panel but you just don't use it

you should adjust your method `panel2()` in like this:

```
private JPanel panel2() 
{
    //JPanel newPanel = new JPanel(); don't create a new panel!
    //CreateAPanel(newPanel, LeftPanel,RightPanel,splitPaneH, panelTop,panelBottom);
    //instead do this:
    JPanel newPanel = CreateAPanel(newPanel, LeftPanel,RightPanel,splitPaneH, panelTop,panelBottom);
    JLabel label = new JLabel ("lalala");
    LeftPanel.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    return newPanel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible to add components to the Panel object afterwards. The only mistake that you have made is that "inside the method body you create new JPanel instances to replace with original param references" so when the method returns there is no effect on the original objects. I suggest doing something different as this:

```
private JPanel[] CreateAPanel(JPanel mainPanel)
    {
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1100, 630));
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        JSplitPane splitPaneH = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
        JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
        JPanel panelBottom = new JPanel();

        splitPaneH.setTopComponent(panelTop);
        splitPaneH.setBottomComponent(panelBottom);
        splitPaneH.setDividerLocation(300);
        splitPaneH.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,630));

        mainPanel.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPanel.add(rightPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

        leftPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (300,630));
        rightPanel.add(splitPaneH);

        return new JPanel[]{mainPanel, leftPanel, rightPanel, panelTop, panelBottom};
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be named e.g. `createPanels` if it returns an array of `JPanels`?

Comment: Yes, it should be. I just tried to make minimum changes in their code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change or add some more components inside result JPanel you get you can set names to all your components when you create them:

```
JPanel newPanel = new JPanel();
newPanel .setName("leftPanel");
resultPanel.add(newPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Then when you get *resultPanel* you can get it's components:

```
Component[] componentList = resultPanel.getContentPane().getComponents();
JPanel leftPanel = null;
for (Component component: componentList) {
    if (Objects.equals(component.getName(), "leftPanel")) {
        leftPanel = (JPanel) component;
    }
}

if (leftPanel != null) {
    // do something
}
```